# Glass cooktop sealed to quartz countertop

Tags: quartz

I have a glass cooktop that is sealed to the quartz countertop with silicone.  From what I have been able to learn the cooktop should not have been sealed to the countertop.  My problem is that one of the cooktop burners won’t ignite and a repairman says the cooktop has to be removed to do the repair.  I am wondering how I can loosen the silicone adhesive in order to lift out the cooktop from the countertop.  Would applying heat with hair dryer loosen the silicone enough?  Looking for suggestions.

Comment: A picture of how your cooktop seats against the countertop would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if dental floss would work on such a large area but if you can get floss in the crack and pull it back and forth it cuts silicone like a hack saw. I find unwaxed floss cuts faster but waxed will also work. I have used this method to remove plastic placards from machine centers when equipment was changed some as large as 18" square I am sure your stove is much larger but it may be worth a try I took the last one off in maybe 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
 I find this knife to be invaluable for numerous jobs. The extendable blade is very sharp. Ease into the space between the cook top and countertop. 
Make multiple passes cutting a little deeper into sealant each time. Applying too much pressure will snap the blade. I always have spare blades because I hang a lot of wallpaper. This thin sharp tool has worked well on a lot of caulk removal jobs for me.

Comment: The pictured blade has many pre-etched, doagonal 'snap off points' where a worn or broken blade can be snapped off to reveal a fresh blade. You have awhile before you need to replace blades.